# Beta by Crashlytics app doesn't install

Tags: android, twitter-fabric, fabric-beta, google-fabric

I added myself as a tester for my Android app. Received and opened the email on my Android device. Got to this screen:

[image: beta download]

Clicked on "Download" and got this:

[image: beta app]

The problem now:  The "INSTALL" button doesn't work, i.e., it's not clickable.

This was on Nexus 5X Android 7.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure there aren't any apps drawing to the screen like screen dimming apps (see: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/69981/why-cant-i-press-the-install-button-when-installing-applications-from-unknown-s).

Comment: Thanks!  I had Iris in paused state but still had to go into settings and force stop it.